# When I running TensorFlow-GPU, it only uses 'Compute_0',Why?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

['Compute_1' isn't working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXwOc.png)

I want to make full use of my GTX1060 6G, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/gpus-in-the-task-manager/) from the MS DirectX blog and seeing that you have what seems to be a single GTX 1060 GPU installed, my best guess is "compute_0" refers to usage of the *primary* or *first* GPU card installed. As for "compute_1", it could display usage if you had a GPU with two "computing" or "rendering" units, or rather a second gpu installed that are linked to each other such as with Nvidia SLI and AMD Crossfire.

Comment: I am only getting usage on compute_1 and not compute_0, and I only have one 1070 TI. How can this be?